# VB.NET - How to split a string?

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, split

In my form I store/create a commandline arguments inside a var to use it later with a control button, to launch a external app with that arguments stored inside my var, and the var contents is a tring like this:

```
ExternalAPP.exe "Argument 1" "argument 2" "argument 3" "more arguments"
```

PS: The arguments are references to folder paths.

And what i need to do is split the var to get all the folder paths (arguments), and make something like this:

```
' Pseudocode
For each folder in var.split(ControlChars.Quote)
    for each file in get.folder.files
     appendline.(new_text_file, file.Name)
  Next
```

Thanks if somebody helps me

**UPDATE**:
the content of the VAR that i need to split is exactly this:

> "F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock"
>   "F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Techno"
>   "F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Pop"

**NOTICE THAT THE FORUM DOES NOT PASTED THE SLASH \ AFTER DRIVE LETTER F:**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
    Dim var As String = "Command.exe ""F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock"" ""F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Techno"" ""F:-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Pop"""
    var = var.Replace(":", ":\").Remove(0, var.IndexOf(" ") + 2)
    Dim dirs As New List(Of String)(var.Split(New String() {""" """}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    Dim files As New List(Of String)()

    For Each path As String In dirs
        Try
            If (Directory.Exists(path)) Then
                files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path))
            Else
                Debug.Print(path & "path does not exists") ' check "Output Window"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(path & ": exception :" & ex.Message)  ' check "Output Window"
        End Try
    Next
```

EDIT:

I just noticed this in your question:

```
NOTICE THAT THE FORUM DOES NOT PASTED THE SLASH \ AFTER DRIVE LETTER F:
```

Comment: thankyou so much, but with your code i get the same exception that in another answer: Illegal characters in path. at line: files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path)), really i don't know how to resolve that, i don't know what illegal characters, or where (Inside the files filenames of the folders?)

Comment: check updated code and post the text printed in "output Window"

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Pop": exception :Illegal characters in path.
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0xee4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xb30) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2452] PlayLists.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2452] PlayLists.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: "you should remove these things =- or -= etc." really? yes i'm on windows, but that is part of the name folder, I need to use it without any exception... I can't do nothing then in any awy? Thankyou for your time and your replies

Comment: You are right path characters allows '-' or '=' etc. Try adding `\` after `drive letter` and make `F:-=` to `F:\-=`. See updated answer.

Comment: F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Pop"path does not exists
 F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock.         The first path exists, but i've noticed that there is a blackquote at the end, i suppose the problem is that

Comment: try using `TrimEnd` method, something like this:  `Directory.GetFiles(path.TrimEnd("\""))`

Comment: nothing to do, you are who helped me mo than other guys so i accept your answer anyway, i've resolved by myself, thankyou for all

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dim Var As String = Command.exe "Argument 1" "argument 2" "argument 3" "more arguments"

dim entries = Var.Split(" "c)

For i As Integer = 1 To entries.Length - 1
   dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(entries(i))
Next
```

Comment: thankyou, but it says "Illegal characters in path." in line:  Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(entries(n)), why?

Comment: my "var" have exactly this content:  "F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Rock" "F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Techno" "F:\-=Temporal=-\Documentos\DVD Temazos\Pop"

Comment: probably because your filename or folder path contains illegal character e.g. if space is not wanted in a file name. Step through your code and check the values of `entries(i)` to know which filename is not well formed

Comment: the filenames or path are not valid

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code doesn't make a lot of sense.  Is it supposed to be a command line, or VB source code?

However, it seems that you want a regular expression to find each string inside quotes.

Regular expressions are tedious to build correctly.  I recommend building a simple regular expression validator, or using one of the web based ones.

Your expression will be something LIKE this (I am not going to validate this):

```
.*(\"(?<filepath>[^"])\")*.*
```

You will want to get all of the match group values for filepath.

If you control your program input, making a friendlier syntax that is easier to parse seems appropriate.

IF these are command line parameters, the commmand shell will parse each quoted parameter for you, and the arguments to your main routine will have them.

I am a C# guy, so a quick google gave me this:

Sub Main()

```
  Dim s() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()

  Console.WriteLine(s(1))
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks for comment, you don't understanded me good, maybe it's my fault (my english is poor), see the other guy who answered me, that's what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to accomplish is parsing command line arguments, try this:

```
Dim files() As String = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx

This line:

```
Var = Command.exe "Argument 1" "argument 2" "argument 3" "more arguments"
```

Might not do what you want. The double quote character needs to enclose the entire string and be escaped:

```
Var = "Command.exe ""Argument 1"" ""argument 2"" ""argument 3"" ""more arguments"""
```

Comment: sorry but isn't that what i need, i've re-updated my first coment, sorry for all this confussion